# PL/PgSQL treats variable name as column name in CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function similar to this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
v_name1 ALIAS FOR $1;

BEGIN

SELECT * from table1 WHERE names_column = v_name1;
RETURN v_name1;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I do

```
SELECT func('Alex');
```

It should run:

```
SELECT * from table1 WHERE names_column = 'Alex';
```

But instead I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "v_name1" does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE names_column = v_name1;
```

How do I tell Postgres to get the TEXT inside the variable to compare?

[EDIT]This is the function I have so far that produces the error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_champ(end_date DATE, champ_name TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
new_champ_name TEXT;
id_of_new_champ INTEGER;
date_of_new_champ DATE;
BEGIN

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW champ AS
SELECT * FROM basketball2 WHERE visitor = champ_name OR home = champ_name;

SELECT MIN(id) INTO id_of_new_champ FROM champ WHERE winner <> champ_name;
SELECT date INTO date_of_new_champ FROM basketball2 WHERE id = id_of_new_champ;
SELECT winner INTO new_champ_name FROM basketball2 WHERE id = id_of_new_champ;
RETURN new_champ_name;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Quick check - if you pass a named parameter, do you get the same issue?

Comment: If I explicitly write 'Alex' into the function instead of the variable, I get no errors. But, then it's not a very useful function.

Comment: Not 'Alex'. I mean if you change your declaration to `CREATE FUNCTION func( vname TEXT)` instead of just passing the data type.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Oh, yea, same thing. Same error.

Comment: @CraigRinger psql version 9.1.12, server version 9.2.4

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Is that the *exact*, unedited code? Or have you "anonymized" it? IF you have, show the *exact* original code.

Comment: @CraigRinger added the exact code that produces the error

Comment: And the original, unedited error its self is ... ? (Running the code on a different database won't produce the same result, since the DB won't have all your tables in it).

Comment: @CraigRinger its the same error on Line 9 where it is trying to create the view by comparing visitor with champ_name. It says column "champ_name" does not exist.

Comment: ARGH! This is why you don't simplify or anonymize your test cases without *running the simplified case to make sure the error still happens*. Answer pending.;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` is not a *plannable statement* in PostgreSQL, it's DDL.

This means it cannot accept query parameters. So PL/PgSQL's normal translation of PL/PgSQL variables into query parameters is not available. It takes the query literally as written.

To get the result you want, you must use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`, e.g.

```
 EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW champ AS
 SELECT * FROM basketball2 WHERE visitor = %L OR home = %L', champ_name, champ_name);
```

... but in this case, creating a view in the first place appears to be nonsensical. Why would you do that, it gains you nothing whatsoever. Just write:

```
SELECT MIN(id) 
INTO id_of_new_champ 
FROM basketball2 
WHERE (visitor = champ_name OR home = champ_name)
  AND winner <> champ_name;
```

Also, **never "simplify" or "anonymize" your code without *clearly saying you have done so* in the question, and *testing that the problem still happens with the simplified code**. Otherwise you're just wasting your time and everybody else's.

Comment: Ok, I will definitely remember to tell people in the future when I simplify the code. Also, THANK YOU! Your solution works!